# Python writing to csv which is named after a class object and found in a folder based on a class object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project and creating a script that creates classes based on objects found in a csv file, connects to an API and downloads data, and then puts this data into a csv file that is named after one of the objects and found in a folder which is named after the objects.

I have created a sample code to illustrate what I am trying to do, but I am getting some errors and tried multiple things but haven't found the solution yet. The sample code is found below.

```
import csv
# class definition
class Person:
   def __init__(self, Name, City, Age):
       self.Name = Name
       self.City = City
       self.Age = Age

# using a list, because it's mutable
Persons = []

# reading csv and filling Persons list
with open('To_Download\\Testentitydownload.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        entity = Person(str(row["Name"]), str(row["City"]), str(row["Age"]))

        # add the new person to the list
        Persons.append(entity)

# writing to a csv file which is based on the Name of the Person, and found in the folder based on the City the Person lives in.
def print_to_file(*args):
    with open('Entities\\'+str(Person.City)+'\\'+str(Person.Name)+'.csv', 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(' '.join(map(str,args)))
        fh.write('\n')

write = print_to_file
Layout = "{!s:1} {!s:2} {!s:3}"
write(Layout.format("Name;", "City;", "Age;"))

# output loop, API stuff.
for person in Persons:
    write(str(person.Name), ";", str(person.City), ";", str(person.Age))
    Writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
```

The problem I am having is that I am unsure how to write to a file found in a folder named after class objects. The code snipped that tries to do this is:

```
# writing to a csv file which is based on the Name of the Person, and found in the folder based on the City the Person lives in.
def print_to_file(*args):
    with open('Entities\\'+str(Person.City)+'\\'+str(Person.Name)+'.csv', 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(' '.join(map(str,args)))
        fh.write('\n')
```

The abovementioned code produces the error:

> AttributeError: type object 'Person' has no attribute 'City'

I have tried multiple things to get this to work, for example

```
# writing to a csv file which is based on the Name of the Person, and found in the folder based on the City the Person lives in.
def print_to_file(*args):
c = str(Person().City)
n = str(Person().Age)
    with open('Entities\\'+c+'\\'+n+'.csv', 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(' '.join(map(str,args)))
        fh.write('\n')
```

which gives the following error:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'Name', 'City', and 'Age'

and a few other things, which all resulted in either one of these 2 errors.

I have been struggling with this for a while now and I was hoping that someone here could help me to make my script save data to these locations while maintaining a similar script structure.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Edited my post to make it easier to read and more accurate.

EDIT 2: allright I figured out the above mentioned issue. Apparently I was not calling the entity but the class person which doesn't work, so now I do not get error messages anymore. The code that i'm currently using for this part is:

```
# writing to a csv file which is based on the Name of the Person, and found in the folder based on the City the Person lives in.
def print_to_file(*args):
    with open('Entities\\'+str(entity.City)+'\\'+str(entity.Name)+'.csv', 'a') as fh:
        fh.write(' '.join(map(str,args)))
        fh.write('\n')
```

The problem now is that the code unfortunately doesn't work proprely.

The Testentitydownload.csv contains the following data:

`Name,City,Age
John,New York,50
Sasha,Minsk,23
Joe,Dallas,76`

the current code only writes to the lowest path, so Instead of writing only John's data in his own file located in the New York folder, respectively for Sasha and Joe, it just writes to Joe's file located in the Dallas folder, 3 times.

I really do not get how this is supposed to happen. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What do you think that: ‘c = str(Person().City.__init__())’ means? Instantiating a Person needs p = Person(n, c, a)

Comment: what exactly does variables c and n do, and what do why do you want the class there

Comment: They are supposed to be a name and a class form the object. In the file that it reads, there are persons with a name, age and a city. the value c should be a string of the city from the class objects. so for example: if the file contains 'John, New York, 50', c = New York and thats the folder location, and n = Name which should be John.csv

Comment: for what the --init-- part, I was trying to solve the attribute error that I described and just tried a bunch of stuff that I found online, this line just happend to be the final thing i tried before i came here

Comment: I think that "with open('Entities\\'+str(Person.City)+'\\'+str(Person.Name)+'.csv', 'a') as fh:" illustrates best what i want to achieve, which is also the first thing i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried cleaning it up a little bit to make it better readable.
This version worked fine for me under Linux and Windows.

```
import csv
import os

# class definition
class Person:
   def __init__(self, name, city, age):
       self.Name = name
       self.City = city
       self.Age = age



def get_persons_from_csv(csv_file):
    persons = list()
    with open(csv_file, mode='r') as fh:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')

        for row in csv_reader:
            try:
                persons.append(
                    Person(
                        str(row["Name"]),
                        str(row["City"]),
                        str(row["Age"])
                    )
                )
            except:
                # Do something in case it fails
                pass
    return persons



def write_person_to_csv(name, city, age):
    dest_dir = os.path.join('Entities', city)
    if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
        os.makedirs(dest_dir)

    csv_file = os.path.join(dest_dir, '{0}.csv'.format(name))
    with open(csv_file, mode='a') as fh:
        fh.write('{0};{1};{2}\n'.format(name, city, age))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    source_csv_dir = 'To_Download'
    source_csv_file = os.path.join(source_csv_dir, 'Testentitydownload.csv')
    persons = get_persons_from_csv(source_csv_file)

    for person in persons:
        print(person.Name, person.City, person.Age)
        write_person_to_csv(person.Name, person.City, person.Age)
```